# Why does left justification not work in the first iteration of a loop?

Tags: c++, cout, justify

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
       using namespace std;

       string s1("Hello1");
       string s2("Hello2");
       
       for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
           
           cout.width(20); cout<<"Some String:"<<left<<s1<<endl;
           cout.width(20); cout<<"Another String:"<<left<<s2<<endl;
           
           cout<<endl;
       }
       return 0;
 }
```

Here is my code. It, to my knowledge, should print s1 and s2 20 characters from the very left of the screen. However, it prints

```
        Some String:Hello1
Another String:     Hello2

Some String:        Hello1
Another String:     Hello2

Some String:        Hello1
Another String:     Hello2
```

I am using onlineGDB to compile, as per instruction of my teacher. What error am I making?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::left` is a "sticky" manipulator, meaning you just set it once. By default, padded strings will be right-justified, which is what happens when you output `"Some String:"` before ever applying the `std::left` manipulator.

See the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/left) which states:

> The initial default for standard streams is equivalent to `right`.

Fixing your code, and tidying it up a bit:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    string s1("Hello1");
    string s2("Hello2");

    cout << left;       
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        cout << setw(20) << "Some String:" << s1 << endl;
        cout << setw(20) << "Another String:" << s2 << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Some String:        Hello1
Another String:     Hello2

Some String:        Hello1
Another String:     Hello2

Some String:        Hello1
Another String:     Hello2
```

Note that I used `std::setw` I/O manipulator from `<iomanip>` instead of the call to `cout.width()`.  This makes the code easier to read and follow.

See the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) for `std::setw`

Answer (score 1):

this statment says

```
cout.width(20); cout<<"Some String:"<<left<<s1<<endl;

set column width to 20,
output "Some String:"
start left justifying
output s1
output end of line
```

you mean

```
cout.width(20);
cout << left;
cout<<"Some String:" << s1 << endl;
```